# Update Panel updates once and causes post back on other triggers

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am dynamically building Image buttons and placing them inside an ASP placeholder. When the user clicks on an image(button) it should update the panel with the school's information. The panel updates correctly the first time a button is clicked but when I click another button it causes a post back. On that second, third, etc... it should update the panel without a post back.

When I am building the buttons I am also creating triggers and setting the control ID to the button's ID. I have debugged and verified that these triggers are being created properly.

**Button and Trigger Creation**

```
 int counter = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in tempTable.Rows)
        {

            var button = new ImageButton
            {
                ID = counter.ToString(),
                CausesValidation = false
                //OnClientClick= "return false;"


            };
            button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(buildSchoolInfo); //The onclick event that builds the school info
            button.CommandName = "ImageButton" + counter.ToString();
            button.CommandArgument = "Test" + counter.ToString();
            SchoolListPH.Controls.Add(button); //Add image button to placeholder

            AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            trigger.ControlID = button.ID;
            //trigger.EventName = "Click";
            schoolInfoUP.Triggers.Add(trigger); //Adding the trigger to the Update Panel

            counter++;

        }
```

**ASPX Code**

```
 <div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SchoolListPH" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>

<%--    This is the literal that builds with all of the selected schools information --%>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="schoolInfoUP" runat="server" >

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litTable" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </ContentTemplate>


</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet for wayyyy to long this single line fixed it for me.

```
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(button);
```

I placed it just after I added the trigger to the update panel.